# After javascript click - alert is opened and IE freezes

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

I'm testing site. Tests are implemented and successfully executed in Chrome and Firefox. Now I try to run them on IE 11. There is such situation: 
I 'm clicking on a link and next step alert should be opened.

```
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElement(By.xpath(String.format(HIT, trademark))));
    pricingAlert.acceptPricingPopup();
```

but on line `executor.executeScript...` IE freezes and in debug mode program does not go to `pricingAlert.acceptPricingPopup();`

Comment: Have you tried to check console in dev tools? Check whether you see any errors in there.

Comment: @Mikhail Program stops on javascript click and give an error org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Comment: but have you tried to reproduce it manually in IE? Maybe you want to increase you ImplicitlyWait timeout?

Comment: @Mikhail this line hasn't any timeout ` executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElement(By.xpath(String.format(HIT, trademark))));` It is just click.
Now I done in different way
 `do {                    
         new Actions(driver).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath(String.format(HIT, trademark)))).click().perform();
                } while (!isDialogPresent());`

Comment: but I think that it isn't a solution, it is just hack

Comment: Well, it's not hack, it's just another way to do it. There are 3 ways to click smthn in webdriver: 1. regular click 2. Through actions 3. Using JS. Seems like 2nd option worked for you. You don't need to do 'move to element', webdriver should do it for you and are you sure that you need to do it while dialog is not present? Maybe it makes sense to explicitly wait for dialog to appear.

Comment: @Mikhail Maybe you do not fully understand problem: program stops at JS clicking, it doesn't go to step wait for alert.
IE can't understand that after JS click alert is appeared